# Database Corruption? Double of every category filter attribute

Tags: category, layout, database, layered-navigation, exception

I added a second category filter area to the category page by adding this to my local.xml:

```
<action method="append"><block>catalog.leftnav</block></action>
```

And output it by add this to my .phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav') ?>
```

It worked, once. Then It threw a Magento exception page, which started:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> You cannot define a correlation name 'sfoi' more than once
>
> Trace:
>
> 0 C:\wamp\www\Project1\lib\Varien\Db\Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', 'am_sales_flat_o...', 'e.entity_id = s...', Array, NULL)
>
> 1 C:\wamp\www\Project1\lib\Zend\Db\Select.php(357): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', 'am_sales_flat_o...', 'e.entity_id = s...', Array, NULL)

I then went back to the category page and found every custom attribute in the navigation filter box is doubled - two of each filter attribute.

I'm guessing it added a join somewhere. Any ideas on how to sort this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catalog/layer` model is loaded as singleton and obviously not intended to be initialized twice.

It will try to prepare its collection twice which results in the error message about duplicated joins and in the duplicated filter attributes.

You could unset the singleton before rendering the second navigation using

```
Mage::unregister('_singleton/catalog/layer');
```

There might be other singletons involved that you need to reset as well. When you look further down at the stack trace you should find out from which model they originate.

Comment: Thanks! So rather than just doing `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav') ?>`, I'd do `<?php Mage::unregister('_singleton/catalog/layer'); echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav'); ?>`? Also, the site is just throwing that exception now, the database seems broken, any ideas how to fix this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, unregister the singleton at this point. As I said, there might be other singletons involved, so if there is another exception message now, look where it comes from. I'm sure, the database is OK.

Comment: Thanks fschmengler, got it. I'll look in to other possible singletons. Regarding the ongoing issue, I got confused. What I meant was I've removed all code that duplicates the block type completely, cleared cache and re-indexed, and the problem is I'm getting two of every custom attribute in the category filter list. I've removed the attributes from Magento completely, added new ones, and the new ones appear in double as well. You can view what I mean [here](http://i.imgur.com/847Dgm6.png), and [here's](http://i.imgur.com/4vzMpQj.png) another. Seems like probable DB damage?

Comment: I'm also wondering how to identify other singletons using the stack trace. I've looked through the error page and not sure how you identified `'_singleton/catalog/layer'` from that! I'd like to look for other singletones but not sure how. I've also output stack trace using `<?php Mage::log(Varien_Debug::backtrace(true, false), null, 'stacktrace.log'); ?>` but that doesn't seem to tell me much either. Much appreciated.

Comment: The problem was an error of mine in app\design\frontend\package\default\template\catalog\layer\view.phtml. This game cracks me up sometimes! I'll let you know if I could do with another helping hand. Cheers! :)

Comment: Since I did not see your stack trace, the catalog/layer singleton information was just based on my experience ;)

Comment: This is now working using just `<?php Mage::unregister('_singleton/catalog/layer'); ?>`. As it's working and I don't know how to identify called singletons, I'm going to mark this as resolved. Many thanks for your time and help.